# Styling body element in fullscreen?

Tags: css, html, fullscreen

My site has a tiling background image applied, which can be seen behind photos as they transition (most photos fill the background).  Have a look here: http://new.element17.com.

When viewed in fullscreen, though (using the button in the top-right in Chrome/Mozilla), this background image disappears and the background is then just `#fff`.  How can I style this?

Based on some reading, I've tried the following:

```
body:-webkit-full-screen {background-image:url(../images/olive.jpg);}
body:-moz-full-screen {background-image:url(../images/olive.jpg);}
body:-ms-full-screen {background-image:url(../images/olive.jpg);}
body:-o-full-screen {background-image:url(../images/olive.jpg);}
body:full-screen {background-image:url(../images/olive.jpg);}
```

But this doesn't result in any change.  Any ideas?

Comment: What browser are you seeing this in? The background image stays just fine for me in Chrome for Windows.

Comment: I'm in Chrome in Windows as well... Let me clear the cache, 1 sec.

Comment: No dice, I'm afraid: http://i.imgur.com/tOU8X.jpg

Comment: Are you browsing the site or from a local copy? Loads fine here as well.

Comment: I'm browsing the site.  Let me try a different browser...

Comment: Okay, trying it from Firefox 16.0.2, I'm having the exact same issue, but the background is black instead of white... http://i.imgur.com/Zw3MO.jpg

Comment: cool site, loads fine in chrome switching on the arrow between fullscreen and back.

Comment: Okay, but when you switch to fullscreen, are you seeing the textured background between slide transitions, or just `#fff`?

Comment: I see the issue here - Chrome/Mac. Unfortunately I'm no help in fixing it. All I can think of is to apply standard background CSS to the body without the sudo classes. But you already have that.

Comment: Ah, at least you can see the issue.  Now I know I'm not crazy, at least.  Thanks anyway!

Comment: Chrome on Win7 works perfectly fine for me also (Version 25.0.1331.0 canary)

Comment: Unable to reproduce, background shows correctly in fullscreen, Chrome 23 on Mac.

Comment: Well it's fixed now, obviously.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm pretty sure if you make a certain element enter full screen mode, rather than doing it on the document object, you can then style from that down.

You'll need to trigger the `requestFullScreen` method on the element you want to make full screen. In this case, it's the root `html` element. This is the method I threw together when I needed it:

```
function enter_full_screen(){
    elem    = document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0];
    calls   = ['requestFullScreen','webkitRequestFullScreen','mozRequestFullScreen'];

    for(var i = 0; i < calls.length; i++){
        if(elem[calls[i]]){
            elem[calls[i]]();
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

And the styles would then become:

```
:-webkit-full-screen body {background-image:url(../images/olive.jpg);}
:-moz-full-screen body {background-image:url(../images/olive.jpg);}
:full-screen body {background-image:url(../images/olive.jpg);}
```

I've put together a quick example page showing this in action: [Example](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/6291374/scratch/2012-11-22.html) (just use the escape key to exit full screen – I didn't bother with the exit button)

Also, according to [the MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Using_fullscreen_mode) on fullscreen mode, no version of IE supports fullscreen mode, and Opera uses the non-prefixed version for triggering, but doesn't support the pseudo-class. You might want to consider manually adding a class to the `html` or `body` elements when entering full screen, and removing it when exiting, if you want to fully support Opera.

Another interesting fact: [the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/:fullscreen#Browser_notes) say Gecko and Webkit use (prefixed) `:full-screen` for the pseudo-class, but the actual W3C proposal uses `:fullscreen` – no dash between the words. I've used both, just to be safe...

Comment: This got me 9/10 of the way there, and now it's working great!  Thank you very much!  The Fullscreen plugin I'm using allowed me to specify the `body` tag as the element to send to full-screen, and I set the background of the `slideshow` element as the texture I wanted.

Comment: Apparently I have to wait 19 hours to award you the bounty... Will do so as soon as I'm able.  Thanks again!

Comment: @Adam I'm having issues with IE not scrolling when in full screen mode. Do you happen to know why this would happen? It works great in chrome and firefox.

Answer (score 1):

I think to get what you want, add your background to `#slideshow` as this is the `div` that is the container when it goes full screen.

```
#slideshow {
    background: url("../images/olive.jpg") repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
}
```